# Binding foreign key after update in asp gridview with entity framework 3.5

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I have been trying to solve the issues for a while. When you create databinding with a foreign key in asp gridview, then you edit a row and change the foreign key in a dropbox for instance, save changes and return back to the view mode (edit row = -1), the value in the foreign key column dissapears (unless it was not changed). However, if you refresh the page (without sending the data again) the value is shown properly, changed as expected.

This also happens in the SPGridView (sharepoint grid view) which inherits from the asp grid view.

Let me show you a very simplified example with update method only:
*(I hope it is not too simplified)*

**The grid**

```
<asp:GridView 
    ID="exampleGridView" 
    runat="server" 
    DataKeyNames="Id" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="false"
    OnRowUpdating="UpdateClick"
    OnRowDataBound="RowDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Id">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Id" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Id") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Login">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Login" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Login") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="EditLoginTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Login") %>' Enabled="false" />
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Role">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Role" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Role.Title") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="EditRoleDropDownList" runat="server" />
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="EditLinkBtn" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="edit" />
        </ItemTemplate>
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateLinkBtn" runat="server" CommandName="Update" Text="update" />
        </EditItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**The code behind**

```
protected void UpdateClick(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    // context taken from constructor, created at the beginning of a request and disposed at the end of a request
    User user = this.ctx.Users.First(u => u.Id == id);

    GridViewRow row = this.exampleGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex];

    user.Login = ((TextBox)row.FindControl("EditLoginTextBox")).Text;

    int roleId =int.Parse(((DropDownList)row.FindControl("EditRoleDropDownList")).SelectedValue);
    if (user.Role.Id != roleId)
    {
        user.Role = ctx.Attach(new Role
        {
            Id = roleId
        });
    }

    this.ctx.SaveChanges();
    this.exampleGridView.EditIndex = -1;
    this.BindGrid();
}

protected void RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow &&
        (e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) == DataControlRowState.Edit)
    {
        var user = (User)e.Row.DataItem;

        var editRoleDropDownList = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("EditRoleDropDownList");
        this.BindRoleDropDownList(editRoleDropDownList);
        editRoleDropDownList.SelectedValue = user.Role.Id.ToString();
    }
}

private void BindGrid()
{
    this.exampleGridView.DataSource = this.ctx.Users.Include(u => u.Role);
    this.exampleGridView.DataBind();
}

private void BindRoleDropDownList(DropDownList roleDropDownList)
{
    // list of roles
    if (this.cachedRoles == null)
    {
        this.cachedRoles = this.ctx.Roles.ToList();
    }

    roleDropDownList.DataSource = this.cachedRoles;
    roleDropDownList.DataValueField = "Id";
    roleDropDownList.DataTextField = "Name";
    roleDropDownList.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simpler than I thought. The proble is in the Update method:

```
int roleId = int.Parse(((DropDownList)row.FindControl("EditRoleDropDownList")).SelectedValue);
if (user.Role.Id != roleId)
{
    // this is the problem
    user.Role = ctx.Attach(new Role
    {
        Id = roleId
    });
}
```

The problem is that I overwrite the role with this new object which has Role.Title equal to empty string obviously. And the object stays there. So the proper solution is following:

```
int roleId = int.Parse(((DropDownList)row.FindControl("EditRoleDropDownList")).SelectedValue);
if (user.Role.Id != roleId)
{
    user.Role = this.ctx.Roles.First(r => r.Id == roleId);
}
```